# TikZ flowchart for a poster

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm making a poster and need to include a flowchart. I've never done this, so I'm starting with the example in the manual. Problem is, it doesn't work.

```
! Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.
```

I googled but none of the solutions found so far fixed this. As I'm a total newb to TikZ, a matrix seems simpler to me, so I would really like to use it.

This is the ME (although I can't compile it, and the errors are different from my full-blown document):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [auto,
        decision/.style={diamond, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=4.5em, text badly centered,inner sep=1pt},
        block/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners,minimum height=4em},
        line/.style={draw, thick, -latex’,shorten >=2pt},
        cloud/.style={draw=red, thick, ellipse,fill=red!20,minimum height=2em}]

    \matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=7mm]
      {
      % row 1
        \node [cloud] (expert){expert}; &
        \node [block] (init){initialize model}; &
        \node [cloud] (system){system}; \\
      % row 2
        & \node [block] (identify) {identify candidate model}; & \\
      % row 3
          \node [block] (update){update model}; &
          \node [block] (evaluate) {evaluate candidate models}; & \\
      % row 4
        & \node [decision] (decide) {is best candidate}; & \\
      % row 5
        & \node [block] (stop){stop}; & \\
      };
\begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
  \path   (init)-- (identify);
  \path   (identify) -- (evaluate);
  \path   (evaluate) -- (decide);
  \path   (update)|- (identify);
  \path   (decide)-| node [near start] {yes} (update);
  \path   (decide)-- node [midway] {no} (stop);
  \path [dashed] (expert)-- (init);
  \path [dashed] (system)-- (init);
  \path [dashed] (system)|- (evaluate);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My question is: what's wrong? This is my first contact with TikZ, so I'm totally lost.

Comment: Your errors are due to \begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]\end{scope}. I don't know enough to know why is that so.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at "Placing nodes using relative placement", Section 3.8 of the TikZ/PGF manual. It might be better than a matrix for what you want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your definition of the `line` style:

```
line/.style={draw, thick, -latex’,shorten >=2pt}
```

That should be `-latex'`, not `-latex’`.

In addition, you mentioned that you're making a poster: do you happen to be using the `beamerposter` package? If so, you can add the `fragile` option to the `frame` to get rid of the `pgfbasematrix` error:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
...
```

Comment: Good catch--I got it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your ampersands with something else. See section 16.5 of the TikZ/PGF manual. I needed to make several changes to the MWE based on answers/comments from ipavlic and LianTze Lim, but given the original error quoted in the question, I maintain that the problem is with ampersands.

Having edited a typo in the definition of `lines` and added the `scopes` library, this compiles for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,matrix,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [auto,
        decision/.style={diamond, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=4.5em, text badly centered,inner sep=1pt},
        block/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners,minimum height=4em},
        line/.style={draw, thick, -latex', shorten >=2pt},
        cloud/.style={draw=red, thick, ellipse,fill=red!20,minimum height=2em}]

    \matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=7mm,ampersand replacement=\&]
      {
      % row 1
        \node [cloud] (expert){expert}; \&
        \node [block] (init){initialize model}; \&
        \node [cloud] (system){system}; \\
      % row 2
        \& \node [block] (identify) {identify candidate model}; \& \\
      % row 3
          \node [block] (update){update model}; \&
          \node [block] (evaluate) {evaluate candidate models}; \& \\
      % row 4
        \& \node [decision] (decide) {is best candidate}; \& \\
      % row 5
        \& \node [block] (stop){stop}; \& \\
      };
\begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
  \path   (init)-- (identify);
  \path   (identify) -- (evaluate);
  \path (evaluate) -- (decide);
  \path   (update)|- (identify);
  \path   (decide)-| node [near start] {yes} (update);
  \path   (decide)-- node [midway] {no} (stop);
  \path [dashed] (expert)-- (init);
  \path [dashed] (system)-- (init);
  \path [dashed] (system)|- (evaluate);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with your MWE. I don't know why. But that's what the problem is: you need to use an ampersand replacement.

Comment: Without replacing ampersands, Santiago's MWE works by removing scope. So the issue might be related to the scope command -- apparently, scopes library was not included.

Comment: Hmm, it worked for me even without the scopes library. I thought the error was a typo in `-latex'`.

Comment: Right... but without the scope env it's useless. Since this is an example from the manual, shouldn't it work?? Thanks for the help so far

Comment: @ipavlic @LianTze Lim The MWE appears to be faulty, but given the error message the OP quotes from their original problem, it looks more likely to be a problem with the ampersands...

Comment: @LianTze You are right. I corrected the typo when testing, and interpreted the resolution of the problem incorrectly. I will delete my answer.

Comment: @ipavlic @Seamus I'm betting my dollar on `beamerposter` being used and that replacing the ampersands or using the `fragile` frame option will get rid of the `pgfbasematrix` error. :) Also, you don't have to include the scopes library for `\begin{scope}...\end{scope}`. Or at least, I thought `\usetikzlibrary{scopes}` was only required if you want to use the shorthand `{...}` for `\begin{scope}...\end{scope}`.

Comment: @LianTze maybe you need the `scopes` library to apply `every path` type style things to a scope? No that doesn't sound right... I don't know why adding that worked...